# How to substitute part of a web path name via regex in order redirect it?

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I never got familiar with regex, so I struggle!

I need an expression after a relaunch of my website (Wordpress) where I need to rename part of a folder name into a new expression like. I use "Redirection" as a plugin that asks for two parameters: source and target urls.

What has to get redirected?
[www.test.com/old/sometext](http://www.test.com/old/sometext) ->  [www.test.com/new/sometext](http://www.test.com/new/sometext)

I tried ro find the first: ^/old/(.*)
and to replcae it by:/new/$1

Well, nothing happens... Help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
\/old\/(.+)$
```

and replace with

```
/new/$1
```

See it on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/WXEyaN/latest

The issues seem to be:

a) the `^` tells the regex to be anchored at the start of a line - omit it.

b) the `/` character needs to be escaped - instead write `\/`.